# Clicking sub menu pop up a modal in wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a Wordpress plugin where I want to open a pop-up modal when I click on one of my plugin sub-menus. I can trigger the modal using a link or a button, but I want to load the modal at the time I click on the submenu.

Code for menu and submenu:

```
<div class="wp-menu-name">Smart Form Builder</div>
<ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap">
<li class="wp-submenu-head">Smart Form Builder</li>
<li class="wp-first-item">
<a class="wp-first-item" href="admin.php?page=smart-form-builder">Create New Form</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="admin.php?page=smart-form-builder-form-list">Form List</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="admin.php?page=smart-form-builder-support">Support</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Code for my model:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_choose_ur_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_choose_ur_formLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><h3>Choose Your Form</h3></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <a href="#tabs" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal_trigger">Click</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to pop up the modal when i click on `Create New Form` submenu. So what i have code in my `sfb_create_form_page` function?
I tried using various way of using javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#modal_choose_ur_form').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

this is working for a simple HTML page quite well but not for my plugin. What can do can anyone help?

Comment: is this a question from a Freelancer ?

Comment: NO. I am learning wordpress and for that i am building a demo plugin project.

Comment: You should give us JsFiddle with HTML,CSS and javascript code. No need of Wurdpress code. Only Html, Css, JS is enough.

Comment: @ jQuery.PHP.Magento.com [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/jtycsrmn/)

Comment: `when I click on one of my plugin sub-menus` , hi , in your jsFiddle, there is NO Dropdown. Post with Dropdown.

Comment: My plugin submenu is written in wordpress how can i add that in jsFiddle?

Comment: Here is the code which will be executed when i click on my plugin sub-menu.

Comment: Take HTML of menu and put in JsFiddle.

Comment: The way you have Popup in HTML in jsfiddle, take your HTML generated and put it in jsFiddle. take html from Firebug.

Comment: Sorry i tried to copy my menu HTML using fire bug. But It didn't seem right. So I think i am too novice to give the required resource to solve my problem.Though i am giving you the link (http://jsfiddle.net/jtycsrmn/4/). Here modal pop-up first but i want after clicking the `Create New Form`

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway for trying to help me

Comment: Hello Bashar sir, please Paste the Firebug Menu Code In Question. So Edit The Question please and put your Drop down HtML.

Comment: HTML for menu has been added as you asked

Comment: So Bushur, you want to open popup on click of Ul LI?

Comment: yes sir.  i want so.

Comment: Is this you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/jtycsrmn/15/ Click on menus below smart builder , Click on ul li With Dots.

Comment: Yes sir i want exactly like this except on load appreance of model at first time. i want just after clicking on ul li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jtycsrmn/16/)**

You need to fire click event on ul li . And open popup when click event is generated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".ulLiOuter ul li").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal_choose_ur_form').modal('show');
    });

});
```

Comment: So i have to wrap my ul li with `ulLiOuter ` class and used this jquery function in my js file?

Comment: yes wrap it, because there will be 100 different UL LI in your HTML, you need to separate out your own LI UL. Getting ?

Comment: Yah i get it. and i am glad you helped me so much but After wrapping up my menus with this class nothing changed. Sorry i think i am wrong with wrapping up in correct place. i wraped up those code which is creating the menu but not working. But your code is correct so i am giving you correct ans.

Comment: @Bashar , see I gave you JsFiddle , which is working. Its your task to update your own code and check against Jsfiddle what is wrong in it. Okay ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this.

Go to wp-admin/nav-menus.php page and open the "Show Settings" from top, Check the (XFN) checkbox then write to xfn input some rel value "like a modal" than add your .js file this code

```
$('a[rel="modal"]').click(function () {
 $("#modal-id").modal(); 
});
```